# How to synchronize search list result with map markers

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, knockout.js

I am using knockoutjs to observe changes in search menu and senchronize them with markers on google maps.

---

Data is separated here and defined at the top as array or places with details about title and Coordinates.

Then Viewmodel which handle how the view will changes.The first view is displaying search menu and the second display some locations with markers

I need to synchronize between search menu results and markers on the map so that only the marker of relevant search result is displayed

**code :**

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title> Nighbour hood map </title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">



    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rwoIResjU2yc3z8GV/NPeZWAv56rSmLldC3R/AZzGRnGxQQKnKkoFVhFQhNUwEyJ" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-vBWWzlZJ8ea9aCX4pEW3rVHjgjt7zpkNpZk+02D9phzyeVkE+jo0ieGizqPLForn" crossorigin="anonymous"></script> 
    <script type="text/javascript" src = "js/lib/knockout-3.4.2.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>

<div class="search-menu ">

  <nav class="navbar navbar-light bg-faded justify-content-between">
      <a class="navbar-brand">Find your favorite place</a>
      <form class="form-inline">
        <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="text" placeholder="Search" data-bind="textInput: filter">
      </form>
  </nav>

  <ul class="list-group" data-bind="foreach: visibleLocations">
    <li class="list-group-item list-group-item-action" data-bind="text: title"  ></li>
  </ul>  

</div>

<div id="map"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
        //data contains title and latitude and longitude
        var model = [
                         {
                            title: 'Park Ave Penthouse',
                            latLng: {lat: 41.7444883, lng: -72.3949465}
                                                  },
                        {
                            title: 'Chelsea Loft',
                            latLng: {lat: 41.2444883, lng: -71.149465}
                        },
                        {
                            title: 'pynsylvania',
                            latLng: {lat: 42.54883, lng: -72.0949465}
                        }

                    ]
    var map,infoWindow;
    var marker =[];

    function ViewModel(){
    var self =this;
    this.filter = ko.observable();

    this.places = ko.observableArray(model);
    //observe changes in the data  and display if search matches
    this.visibleLocations = ko.computed(function(){

          return this.places().filter(function(places){
              if( !self.filter() || 
               places.title.toLowerCase().indexOf(self.filter()) !== -1) {
                return places;
              }

            });
      },this);

    }
  var viewModel = new ViewModel();
  ko.applyBindings(ViewModel);
  //google maps initialization
  function initMap() {

    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    center: {lat: 42.360091, lng: -71.09416},
    zoom: 8
    });
      infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

      viewModel.forEach(function(place){

      place.marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position:place.latLng,
      map: map,
      animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
      title : place.title
    });

    place.marker.addListener('click', function() {

      infowindow.setContent('<div><strong>' + this.title + '</strong><br>' + 
        '<img src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/streetview?size=300x200&location='+this.title+'=151.78&pitch=-0.76&key=AIzaSyCX6bSgdTWvavwA0O8B7KsObZhE5GAf6yQ" >'
      );

            infowindow.open(map, this);
          });

    });

  }

  function initMap() {

    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    center:  {lat: 42.360091, lng: -71.09416},

    zoom: 8
    });
      infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

      viewModel.places().forEach(function(place){

    place.marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position:place.latLng,
      map: map,
      animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
      title : place.title
    });

    place.marker.addListener('click', function() {

      infowindow.setContent('<div><strong>' + this.title + '</strong><br>' + 
        '<img src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/streetview?size=300x200&location='+this.title+'=151.78&pitch=-0.76&key=AIzaSyCX6bSgdTWvavwA0O8B7KsObZhE5GAf6yQ" >'
      );

            infowindow.open(map, this);
          });

    });

       }
</script>


    <script 
    src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCX6bSgdTWvavwA0O8B7KsObZhE5GAf6yQ&callback=initMap"/
       async defer> 
    </script>
```

Comment: it solve the issue but need to understand the idea behind it

Comment: to address your issue of understanding idea behind it. here is a nice site about utility functions in knockout.  http://www.knockmeout.net/2011/04/utility-functions-in-knockoutjs.html the filter section is probably the one that addresses your search requirement.

Comment: thanks@BryanDellinger